# VBA Count number of series in a chartObject

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I know this seems straightforward but it doesn't seem to work for me.
I have a chart on "Sheet1". It is the only chart on the sheet. I want to get the number of series in the chart. So I use:

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection.Count
```

to get the answer in the immediate window. However VBA gives me a "Object doesn't support property or method" error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add in `Chart`:

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
```

Comment: @harryg - Thanks. And don't feel silly. I've not always found manipulating charts using VBA intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Try this `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count`