# Update chart with different series

Tags: excel, vba, charts, macros

I'm using this piece of code in an excel macro to force the update of a large number of overlayed charts:

```
Set sht = ActiveSheet
For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
    co.Activate

    For Each sc In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        sc.Select
        temp = sc.Formula
        MsgBox temp
        sc.Formula = "=SERIES(,,1,1)"
        sc.Formula = temp
    Next sc
Next co
```

The code works good but on a chart which has a series of 5 elements (instead of 4) I got an error on this line:

```
sc.Formula = "=SERIES(,,1,1)"
```

Could you suggest me how to modify the code in order to get it working for all my charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've solved with this code:

```
Set sht = ActiveSheet
For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
    co.Activate
    For Each sc In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        temp = sc.Formula
        'Counting commas in formula
        counter = Len(temp) - Len(Replace(temp, ",", ""))
        'If commas were 3 then 4 params
        If counter = 3 Then
            sc.Formula = "=SERIES(,,1,1)"
        'If commas were 4 then 5 params
        ElseIf Count = 4 Then
            sc.Formula = "=SERIES(,,,1,1)"
        End If

        sc.Formula = temp

    Next sc
Next co
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 values in **=SERIES(,,1,1)** because it's a series of 4 elements.

If there are 5 elements (or more, or less), you'll have to count these elements.

I don't know if **ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count** counts the elements of a seriescollection.

```
Dim tmpText As String

tmpText = ""

For i = 3 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count

    tmpText = tmpText & ",1"

Next i

sc.Formula = "=SERIES(," & tmpText & ")"
```

I'm starting here at *3* because the first 2 values in **=SERIES(,,1,1)** are empty.

The result would be if **ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count** is *5*:

> sc.Formula = "=SERIES(,,1,1,1)"

It's necessary to set *i = 1* in the for-loop in case you have less than 3 elements.

You should try it by yourself. :)

**Edit**

[image: SeriesCollection.Count]

Comment: Thank you, I'm giving it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately SeriesCollection doesn't have a method Count so I still don't know how to distinguish the different charts.

Comment: ActiveSheet.SeriesCollection.Count - just type it in... I just don't know whether it's the right return value.

Comment: I've tried but when I've used the count method for the sc inside the "for loop" it gave me a runtime error number 438. It was saying "properties or method not supported by the object". It happens even if i put only "a=sc.count" or "msgbox sc.count"

Comment: Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363812/vba-count-number-of-series-in-a-chartobject